# Top 10 terms grouped by two factors pyspark

Tags: python, database, pyspark

i have the following dataframe:

```
+--------------------+-------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+----------+
|                user|    sku|          category|               query|          click_time|          query_time|            city|    country|      location|time_spent|
+--------------------+-------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+----------+
|212dffe34129f84ac...|2842092|pcmcat209000050008|           Hp tablet|2011-08-21T11:09:...|2011-08-21T11:07:...|          Reusel|Netherlands|51.3625,5.1653|        13|
|fc3540111a0aaca56...|2969477|pcmcat247400050000|Toshiba satellite...|2011-09-08T22:22:...|2011-09-08T22:22:...|          Reusel|Netherlands|51.3625,5.1653|        60|
|3eb03056dd77ccad8...|6974946|      abcat0410012|             oltmpus|2011-08-28T19:11:...|2011-08-28T19:08:...|            null|Netherlands|   52.3667,4.9|         0|
|0ae72d93c4b9394d5...|9755322|pcmcat247400050001|           hp laptop|2011-09-05T15:34:...|2011-09-05T15:33:...|Roelofarendsveen|Netherlands|52.2033,4.6333|         4|
|dd99a827d4790eaf3...|2363054|      abcat0101001|     Samsung LCD 550|2011-09-01T10:29:...|2011-09-01T10:28:...|            null|Netherlands|   52.3667,4.9|        42|
|fa7bf9fb76ef1abe3...|9643151|      abcat0404004|        memory stick|2011-09-06T17:17:...|2011-09-06T17:15:...|            null|Netherlands|   52.3667,4.9|         0|
|037180033c5941c86...|9929926|          cat02015|              Castle|2011-08-28T22:07:...|2011-08-28T22:06:...|       Tarragona|      Spain|  41.1167,1.25|         6|
|45bebf83124cef122...|1303083|      abcat0508009|    microsoft office|2011-08-30T19:33:...|2011-08-30T19:31:...|       Tarragona|      Spain|  41.1167,1.25|        20|
|86fa480fe4ff0abac...|2842056|pcmcat209000050008|Inventory checker...|2011-09-06T18:17:...|2011-09-06T18:17:...|            null|    Belgium|    50.85,4.35|        37|
|0d1521a7bbe3973d6...|1014055|      abcat0201010|                Zune|2011-08-25T12:24:...|2011-08-25T12:23:...|            null|Netherlands|   52.3667,4.9|         0|
```

and i want the data to be grouped by the query name. But not only that, I just want the top 10 query-names from belgium and netherlands. So firstly i grouped the data like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct, avg, stddev


mydf= df.groupBy(df.query).count()


mydf= mydf.orderBy(mydf["count"].desc())

mydf= mydf.limit(11)

mydf = mydf.dropna()
mydf.show()

+--------------------+-----+
|               query|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|         Hp touchpad|  271|
|         hp touchpad|  193|
|            Touchpad|  151|
|LaborDay_Computer...|  138|
|            touchpad|  128|
|           Hp tablet|   88|
|LaborDay_Televisi...|   86|
|                iPad|   65|
|             Laptops|   63|
|                Ipad|   61|
+--------------------+-----+


mydf= df.groupBy(when(col("country") == "Netherlands", df.groupBy(df.query))).count()
```

but I dont know, how to match it with the countries Netherlands and Belgium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `filter`. I took sample data from your dataset. but the logic should work for your dataset as well.

```
    #InputDF
    # +-----------+-----------+
    # |    country|      query|
    # +-----------+-----------+
    # |netherlands|hp touchpad|
    # |netherlands|       ipad|
    # |      india|   touchpad|
    # |    belgium|       ipad|
    # +-----------+-----------+

    filtered_df = df.filter("country in ('netherlands', 'belgium')")

    filtered_df.show()

    # +-----------+-----------+
    # |    country|      query|
    # +-----------+-----------+
    # |netherlands|hp touchpad|
    # |netherlands|       ipad|
    # |    belgium|       ipad|
    # +-----------+-----------+

    filtered_df.groupBy("query").count().orderBy(F.desc("count")).limit(10).show()

    # +-----------+-----+
    # |      query|count|
    # +-----------+-----+
    # |       ipad|    2|
    # |hp touchpad|    1|
    # +-----------+-----+
```

Comment: Yes it does, Thank you. Had some issues at frist because it said "country" there. Now I create two dataframes for Belgium and Netherlands. Thank you it works perfectly :)